# moment api method to calculate Today's time in milliseconds

Tags: javascript, momentjs

```
var timeArr = moment().format('HH:mm').split(':');
var timeInMilliseconds = (timeArr[0] * 3600000) + (timeArr[1] * 60000);
```

This is my current solution. I'd rather use the [moment api](http://momentjs.com/docs/) to calculate today's time (time since 12:00am today) in milliseconds.

My code returns today's time in milliseconds. I need to call another function in milliseconds. I can not use the epoch. I need today's time formated in milliseconds.

Examples:

```
9:00am = 3.24e+7 milliseconds 
9:00pm = 6.84e+7 milliseconds.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
var moment = require("moment");
// Compute the time in milliseconds assuming it's 1AM now
moment("1:00","HH:mm")-moment("00:00","HH:mm")
// 3600000


// Compute the time in milliseconds assuming it's 9AM now
moment("9:00","HH:mm")-moment("00:00","HH:mm")
// 32400000

// Compute the time in milliseconds assuming it's 9PM now
moment("21:00","HH:mm")-moment("00:00","HH:mm")
// 75600000

// For current time
moment()-moment("00:00","HH:mm")
```

Comment: // For current time
moment()-moment("00:00","HH:mm")

Comment: // For current time
moment()-moment("00:00","HH:mm")

Comment: Idk how to delete my comments ^ but this seems to work, I just don't understand why though. Read through the docs and can't find.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following functions:

- `moment()` - this gives you the current moment ("now")
- `startOf('day')` - this gives you the first moment of the day
- `diff` - this calculates the difference between two moments

Putting it together:

```
moment().diff(moment().startOf('day'))
```

The default units are milliseconds, so you don't need to specify them.

This gives you the elapsed milliseconds since the start of the day.  However, note that there are some time zones (Brazil, for example) where the DST spring-forward transition occurs right at the stroke of midnight - on such days, the clocks go from 23:59:59 to 01:00:00, so the first moment of the day might not be midnight!  In that situation, values returned by the above function might appear to be off by an hour from what you expect.  It is indeed returning time since the start of the day, just not time from "midnight".

To compensate for this possibility, you can do the following instead:

```
moment().utcOffset(0, true).diff(moment().utcOffset(0, true).startOf('day'))
```

The `utcOffset(0, true)` will flip to UTC mode while keeping the local time intact.  This is a little more convoluted than the first example, but gets the job done because UTC never experiences DST transitions.